# Plot data points according to the pairwise distance matrix

Tags: data-analysis, clustering, data-mining

Consider eight data points. The following matrix (i.e., a symmetric matrix with the lower triangle elements) shows the pairwise distances between any two points.

- 0
- 11 0
- 5 13 0
- 12 2 14 0
- 7 17 1 18 0
- 13 4 15 5 20 0
- 9 15 12 16 15 19 0
- 11 20 12 21 17 22 30 0

Is it possible to plot all these eight data points in a two-dimensional space where the distance metric between every two points is the Euclidean distance and the above matrix can be satisfied? If yes, please draw all eight data points. If no, please state whether there exists a d-dimensional space where d > 2 such that the above matrix can be satisfied with the eight data points in this space. In this case, if there exists, please give the smallest value of d and give all eight data points in this d-dimensional space. Otherwise, please explain it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to reformulate this problem as a multiple quadratic equation set (with 8d variables and 28 equations). And I tried to solve the equation set by using Matlab, where I gradually increase d. However, the Matlab returns 'Empty sym: 0-by-1' for d=1,2,3,4,5, so I intutively think the equation set has no solution. Maybe it's impossible to plot the data points in any space, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: What you are looking for is MDS(Multidimensional Scaling). [https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/NCSS/Multidimensional_Scaling.pdf](https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/NCSS/Multidimensional_Scaling.pdf)